# generic method for building an array

Tags: c#

Below is a simplified example of a method I have implemented.

```
public double[] CreateArray(double[] input)
{
  var output = new double[10];

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
  {
    output[i] = input[i] * 3.14;
  }

    return output;
}
```

I have another use case that would be the same except i would like to return an array of objects:

```
public Series[] CreateArray(double[] input)
{
  var output = new Series[10];

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
  {
    output[i] = new Series(i, input[i] * 3.14);
  }

  return output;
}
```

Can this be made generic enough to use in either case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make a method that converts `double[]` input to some `T` with a lambda:

```
static T[] Convert<T>(IEnumerable<double> input, Func<double,T> converter) {
    return input.Select(converter).ToArray();
}
static T[] Convert<T>(IEnumerable<double> input, Func<double,int,T> converter) {
    return input.Select(converter).ToArray();
}
```

Call this method like this:

```
double[] res1 = Convert(input, d => d * 3.14);
Series[] res2 = Convert(input, (d, i) => new Series(i, input[i] * 3.14));
```

Note that since the conversion is a single line, you might as well use `Select` directly:

```
double[] res1 = input.Select(d => d * 3.14).ToArray();
Series[] res2 = input.Select((d, i) => new Series(i, input[i] * 3.14)).ToArray();
```

Straight LINQ approach gives your users "instant familiarity" because they wouldn't have to navigate to your `Convert` method to see what it does.

Answer (score 1):

### This will no work for non newable primitives such as booleans so it should be avoided.  Only here to help others spot this.

You could create a generic method with a constraint that the item is newable

```
public T[] CreateArray<T>(double[] input) where T: new()
{
    var output = new T[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        output[i] = (T) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), new object[] { i, input[i] * 3.14 });;
    }

    return output;
}
```

Comment: This won't work for type double or other class types which are not type Series.

Comment: @RyanWilson You're absolutely right.  I've updated the item so people know to avoid this solution (and don't repeat my mistake!)

Comment: It was a valiant attempt.